# How to convert color names to its equivalent hex code?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I want to display the TextView's text at particular color in which i am getting from server. From server colors are coming in string format. Like "YELLOW", "BLUE", "RED", "PURPLE" etc.
    How can we set this color to textview's text.

Can anybody have any idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: how many colors are we talking about ?

Comment: these colors can be anything, it's from server

Comment: if you have a limited number of colors then manage yourself with a class or with database with the name and code of color

Comment: You should ask the server to send you colors in hex format, like #1034f4, or 0x1034f4

Comment: Could it be like Crayola crayon colors like NEON_CARROT or my personal favorite MAC_N_CHEESE?

Comment: Better do the conversion on server-side and receive colors as int/hex values. If possible of course.

Answer (score 8):

If the server cannot send hex format as [Redwarp's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185120/convert-color-string-to-int#comment50375592_31185120) says, you can do basic colours like this;

```
Color.parseColor("RED")
```

**[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))**

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the
>   string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception.
>   Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green',
>   'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray',
>   'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuschia',
>   'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'

or create a `color.xml` in the values resource folder and create the colour resources like this;

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("RED"));
```

it will help you-